# Work out how many more 5 star reviews required to increase a rating out of 10 by 0.1 points

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I hope you can help me out here. I don't know the technical wording for what I am trying to solve here so it is likely this has been asked and answered before in some shape form or fashion but I have no idea how to word it to find it, so please forgive duplication if this is the case.

OK so picture this, we have a total of 3160 ratings

(10 x 1 star; 50 x 2 star; 100 x 3 star; 500 x 4 star; 2500 x 5 star)

we get a rating out of 10 of 9.4 (rounded from 9.436709). The way we are working out distribution is the percentage of the total ratings count for each group

(1 star = 0.316... % of 3160)

and then taking that as a weighted figure

(1 star = 1/5 of 0.316... %; 2 star = 2/5 of 1.582...%; etc...)

I managed to get this far with no problems.

The question is, how can I work out, without randomly picking numbers, how many more 5 star reviews are required to achieve a rounded rating of 9.5?

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: you would need to change the basic proportions of 5*:sub5* ratings

Comment: I wish I had a clue what that means or how I go about that.

Comment: are you assuming the votes come in as usual, because you will never get to 9.5, or are you assuming that all votes from now on will be $5\star$?

Comment: I want to work off the assumption that all following votes will be 5 stars.

Comment: Just for reference, I would say this is a "weighted average" situation. I'm sure someone will answer eventually, and the ideas will apply to any other "weighted average" you may encounter.

Comment: Weighted averages may be somewhat involved but a google of that has helped me solve another issue so thank you for that, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your value of 9.4367.... is coming by giving 2 points for each star, and dividing by 3160, i.e. $2(10\cdot 1 + 50\cdot2 + ... + 2500\cdot5)/3160$ = 29820/3160

Since we want the rating to be 9.5, if *x* more 5 star ratings are obtained,

we want $\frac{29820+10x}{3160+x} = 9.5$

$29820 + 10x = 3160\cdot9.5 + 9.5x$

$0.5x = 200$

*x* = 400 more 5 star ratings

*Edit*

For a *rounded* rating of 9.5, $\ge 9.45$ is enough, so we use

$29820 + 10x = 3160\cdot9.45 + 9.45x$, which yields $x = 77$

Comment: The OP asks for a rounded rating of 9.5, so I think 9.45 would be sufficient (+1 though)

Comment: Edit added following your keen observation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help one and all. I just need to apply this to my program now.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Update: I really had to work hard to work that back but with the help of our in house algebra wiz we worked it back into a working formula for our program needs. So thank you again. For those interested: (where T = target) x = [(count * T) - starScore] / (10 - T)

Comment: The formula should be [(count * T) - 2*(star score)] / (10 - T), because we gave 2 points for each star.